# How can I block specific domains on Windows, only for certain users?

Tags: windows, dns, windows-firewall, administration, web-filtering

I want to limit what websites I can view when logged in under an account. I don't think it's possible to accomplish this via the hosts file or router. Ideas for good/free solutions?

Comment: Posting what specific Operating System you are using would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windows firewall.

Set up a block rule for a website, then open up the properties and go to the users tab, and set up who it should apply to.

I can only vouch for this working in Windows 7.

The user tab in the properties window looks like this:

[image: firewall rule properties, users tab]

### Update

Sorry for my mistake.

You can only block IP address ranges, not URLs, but IP address are trivial to find out for websites.

At the command prompt, just ping the website you want to block:

[image: command prompt for ping]

Then in the users tab of the properties window, just select the users that should be allowed to skip this rule.

Comment: Could you provide more detail regarding how to set up a block rule with the firewall for a specific domain? I only see options for blocking ip ranges.

Comment: This isn't really helpful for the large websites that I'm trying to block, which use numerous ip addresses. I know you can block ranges, but, I'd rather not block large portions of the internet which don't need to be blocked.

Comment: Also, it looks like those user options only work when "Allow only secure connections" is the action, not "Block the connection".